# How to combine results of two query from Eloquent Model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have two query to database:

```
$words = Word::where('word','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
               ->limit(10)
               ->get();

$words_default = DefaultWord::where('word','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
               ->limit(10)
               ->get();
```

How I can combine results to one var?

Comment: use model relation or use query builder `DB` with `join`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `merge` method:

```
$merged = $words->merge($words_default);
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-merge